# CSS float breaking HTML image map

Tags: html, css, css-float, imagemap, madcap

I am using an XML editor called Madcap Flare that allows me to create image maps using a GUI. Since that makes the maps easily editable, I would rather use that technique. Unfortunately, the code it renders is not a CSS image map, but an HTML one (map, area, etc.). I do not want to switch to a CSS image map, because I want to do easy editing in the GUI.

I want my image map to align right with text to the left of it. I have tried the following techniques with the indicated results:

Technique 1: I floated the div containing the image right with CSS. 
Result: The image map no longer works, but the image floats right and the text wraps.

Technique 2: I floated the image right with CSS.
Result: The image floats right, but the div remains on the left. The text does not wrap and the image map no longer works.

Technique 3: I set the div align="right" and removed the CSS completely. 
Result: The image floats right and the image map works, but the text no longer wraps.

I've noticed the image map only breaks when I float the image or its container; I even floated left to experiment and saw the same results. Is there no way to float an image map? I wondered if the issue were an image resizing issue, but I inspected the code and the image map is no inheriting any image size styles. I also set the image to max-width and max-height 100% in my tests to make sure it wasn't shrinking at all, but I saw the same results again. I also think that the HTML align=right experiment indicated that the problem was not an inherited style.

Any tips/tricks? Or any confirmation that you cannot float an image map? Thanks.

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the div containing the image map has a fixed size and is at the upper border of its parent DIV, you could do the following:

Create an empty DIV with the same size as the one containing the image map and make that `float right` (at the top). No border, no background, no contents. The text will float around that one.

Apply `position: relative` to the parent DIV and `position: absolute` to the div containing the image map. Apply `top: 0;`,  `right: 0` and the `width` and `height` as the empty floated DIV.

This places the image map above the empty floated DIV and the text floats around it.